# MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 | Intel macOS monterey

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use macOS monterey (intel). I tried installing mongodb manually. Same problem. I used homebrew to install mongodb-community@6.0. Same problem.

Nomatter what I try. I get this error. Please help!!!

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB?

Comment: Just upgrade macOS to 13.2 & 'mongodb-community' fails to run 6.0.3 & 6.0.4.

Answer (score 10):

For me, it worked just by `stopping` and `starting` the **MongoDB community service**

First Stop the service

`brew services stop mongodb-community`

then Start it again

`brew services start mongodb-community`

Answer (score 4):

I have had exactly the same problem, though on an M1 Mac. After a lot of googling mongo.log messages and changing ownership and group of various files, I managed to get mongo up and running again by reverting to version 5.

The sequence which should get you up and running is:

```
brew services stop mongodb-community
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@5.0
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@5.0
```

A quick check using mongosh indicated all was up and running with no loss of data. I made a copy of my data before I made any changes, just in case:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/var
cp -a mongodb mongodbsave
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **MongoDB Community 7.0.2** perfectly. I've just upgraded **macOS 14.2** (23C64).

Brew:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/bin/install_compass
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/bin/mongod
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/bin/mongos
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/macos_mongodb.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/MPL-2
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/7.0.2/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

Now I get:

```
brew services start mongodb-community
Error: undefined method `plist_startup’ for #
Did you mean? plist_name
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/formula_wrapper.rb:71:in `service_startup?’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:280:in `service_load’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:122:in `block in start’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:97:in `each’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/services_cli.rb:97:in `start’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/lib/service/commands/start.rb:12:in `run’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services/cmd/services.rb:130:in `services’
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:86:in `’
MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiFY$
```

**'FIXED'**

Services not work:

```
brew services restart/stop/start
```

Could only work with:

```
./mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Also:

'Brew' does not 'upgrade' to: MongoDB Community 7.0.4

Answer (score -1):

There aren’t a lot of solutions for Mac that I could find, but this worked right away.

First **stop** the service

```
brew services stop mongodb-community
```

Then **start** it again

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Share
Edit
Follow

Answer (score -1):

it worked for me:

stop the service

brew services stop mongodb-community

Then start it again

brew services start mongodb-community